# Windows Phone 8.1 and OData Service

Tags: windows-phone, odata, windows-phone-8.1

How can I call a Odata Service from my Windows Phone 8.1 App. There is no "Add Service Reference". Microsoft don't support this feature anymore for xaml Windows Phone 8.1 Apps.

How can I bind this Odata Service now?

Any ideas...

thanks

regards...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebAuthenticationBroker`

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx)

[Windows Universal Apps Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

Vittorio Bertocci wrote a great article to demonstrate how to use `WebAuthenticationBroker` with Office365 api (EWS/OData)

[Link to the blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/16/calling-office365-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-1-app/)

Answer (score 0):

"Add Service Reference" is not supported any more, but a new one is in the landscape: T4. Please take a look at this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx.